# Optimization and Security of file upload on nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, optimization, upload

I have a nodejs server.

1. Users are allowed to upload files on the server.
2. Files are received in chunks of 250kB.
3. When all chunks have been received, chunks are combined into complete file.
4. If network fails on the client, frontend intermittently checks for network for a period of two hours, to complete the process of sending all chunks to the server.
5. Chunks are stored in Uint8 arrays (in server heap).

If a hacker decides to send lots of incomplete file parts, then heap of my server could be exhausted. I can increase the heap, but that is not a proper solution.

Is it recommended to write small files from individual chunks, which are combined into a complete file (once all parts have been received), rather than store chunks in Uint8 arrays in server heap?

Will it be too taxing on I/O, to create files from individual chunks?

(server has SSD drives)

Comment: Do you keep track of the chunk id's so to speak so you can reassemble in the right order, or does the client just upload the files in order synchronously?

Comment: Yup, order of chunks is tracked as client cannot be trusted to send chunks in correct order!

Comment: I would personally just write them to disk instead of memory, and assemble from disk later. I would just use a `WritableStream` and test multiple concurrent file uploads to check for load on the server.